# Monitoring memory changes with page_guard protection

Tags: winapi, memory-address

There is a specific memory region (a DWORD value) that keeps changing and I want to track these changes.

I decided to protect the region with PAGE_GUARD so I know when the region is accessed:

```
int main(void)
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(exception_filter);

    //The memory region I want to monitor
    DWORD* addr= (DWORD*)0x00B8CFD0;

    //Add page guard protection
    DWORD oldProtection;
    if (!VirtualProtect(addr, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldProtection))
        return 1;

    //The exception will occur and at this point I know the memory was accessed
    *addr = 1000;

    return 0;
}

LONG WINAPI exception_filter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExcepPointers)
{
    if(pExcepPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION)
    {
        //the memory region is being accessed
        //but how can I track the new modification?
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}
```

This works fine, however, I'd like to read the new value (in this case, 1000) from within the exception_filter. Is that possible?

I've tried every property from pExcepPointers and so far couldn't get anything related.

Comment: The CPU does not provide this information. You can try to parse the faulting instruction. Or you can set the trap flag and let the processor single-step, and then look at the memory again.

Comment: or you can set `DRn` (`0<=n<=3` ) breakpoint on data write, exception will *after* data is write to memory region. but this is per thread breakpoint. so you will be need set this for all threads, which can access this data

Comment: I didn't know about trap flag, but it worked fine, thank you! I should be able to use this trick without any problems, right?

Comment: Assuming that the program is not playing its own tricks with the trap flag and assuming that no other thread writes to the memory in the meantime.